# Prove if $|a_{n+1}|/|a_n| \leq |b_{n+1}|/|{b_n}|$ and $\sum |b_n|$ is convergent, then $\sum |a_n|$ is convergent

Tags: calculus, analysis

How do I prove that if $|a_{n+1}|/|a_n| \leq |b_{n+1}|/|{b_n}|$ and $\sum |b_n|$ is convergent, then $\sum |a_n|$ is convergent? I know that if I can get $|b_{n+1}/{b_n}| < 1$ then I can use the ratio test to say $\sum a_n$ is convergent, but I don't know if this the proper way to approach the problem.

Comment: The statement is not necessarily true as it stands. Try it with $a_n = (-1)^n n$ and $b_n = 1/n^2$.

Comment: yes, there should probably be absolute values on both ratios. Further, are you assuming that this inequality holds for all $n$? or that this holds for the lim sup? or something else?

Comment: This statement probably assumes that $\{a_k\}$ and $\{b_k\}$ are positive sequences.

Comment: Right, I meant to put absolute values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** show that $|a_n|\le|b_n|\dfrac{|a_1|}{|b_1|}$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: If $\sum b_k$ converges and successive terms in the sequence $\{b_k\}$ have greater absolute ratios, then what can you say, using the comparison test, about a sequence with smaller absolute ratios?