Show $\sum b_n$ converges then $\sum a_n$ converges when $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\leq \frac{b_{n+1}}{b_n}$
Having trouble with this question about converging series
Let $\sum b_n$ and $\sum a_n$ be positive series for which $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\leq         \frac{b_{n+1}}{b_n}$ Show if $\sum b_n$ converges then $\sum a_n$ converges
My direction was using the fact that $\sum a_n$ is a positive series, so the sequence of partial sums is monotonic increasing and if I prove that its bounded above then the series converges.  I tried using the fact that $\sum b_n$ converges so that $S_n<M$ for some $M\in\mathbb R$ and somehow bounding $\sum a_n$ but that's where I got lost.
Would appreciate the help.

Are you sure it should be $a_n+1$ and not $a_{n+1}$ (and similarly for $b$) in the given inequality?

yep that's my bad, how do i fix this?

enclose subscripts and superscripts in their own { } for multiple characters. Braces are basically like parentheses in latex

In your work, you mention very broad strategies but nothing specific to the problem.  For instance, you never mention the inequality in your work.  Do you have an idea of what that inequality tells you?  (If you really have no clue, try writing it out for $n=1$ and $n=2$ both and see what those imply)

Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2019616/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/329003/42969 – all found with Approach0

Well, since we have $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \le \frac{b_{n+1}}{b_{n}} $ with $a_n, b_n$ positive for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, it follows that $\prod_{n=0}^{N} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \le \prod_{n=0}^{N} \frac{b_{n+1}}{b_{n}} \implies a_{N+1} \le \frac{a_0}{b_0} b_{N+1}$ and now the claim should follow by the comparison test.
